# How objects are stored in memory - Java (c++)

Tags: java, c++

I have a memory question regarding creating objects in java-language.

When one creates an object in java a certain memory-space is occupied on the heap - correct? But what is part of this memory? Is it membervariables or both membervariables and methods? Could it be so that several object that refers to the same class share something?

Let say I have the following class

```
 class MyClass {

     //Membervariables
     protected int age;
     protected long dateOfBirth;


    /**
     * Constructor  
     * @param age
     */
    public MyClass(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param dateOfBirth
     */
    protected void setDob(long dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    protected int getAge() {   
        return this.age;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    protected long getDob() {
        return this.dateOfBirth;
    }
  }
```

So in this class I have the following:
- Two membervariables - one **int** and one **long**

- one constructor
- one mutator-method
- one accessor-method.

In the main-method I create two-instances (objects) of this class:

```
 MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass(10);
 MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass(11);
```

So my question is:

1) How could this be depicted in the computers memory?

2) Could the same "architecture" of how things are stored in memory concerning objects be applied to c++ as well?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The Java Language Specification does not specify such things. It's up to each JVM implementation..

Answer (score 3):

An object consists of a pointer to the internal version of the class, an area used for `synchronized` locking, an area of GC flags, and the instance fields defined in the class.  (Note that an object reference field is only a pointer -- the referenced object is allocated separately.)

Methods are located by following the class pointer to the class and indexing a method table in the internal class object.

Your object above, in a 64-bit JVM, would be roughly:

- Class pointer - 8 bytes
- Lock variable - 8 bytes
- GC flags - 4 bytes
- Hash value - 4 bytes
- dateOfBirth - 8 bytes
- age - 4 bytes

36 bytes total.  (Less, of course, in a 32-bit JVM.)  The 36 bytes would likely be rounded up to 48 bytes to put it on a 16-byte boundary, or at least 40 to put it on an 8-byte boundary.

(This is one possible implementation.  There are tricks that can be used to reduce/combine the space for the lock and GC fields, eg.  But the basic principles apply.)

Comment: Where's you identity hash code? I believe it tends to be more compact than this, although with plenty of alignment.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - Yep, I forgot the hash.  I believe in the versions I've seen it shared space with the GC flags.

Comment: And there are various ways to do without the lock field, usually by swapping it with the class pointer in a weird way.

Comment: The object header is smaller than that ... I understand.  For instance, the full identity hash is only stored if required; e.g. if `identityHashcode(obj)` has been called, AND the object then survives then next GC.  And the lock and class "pointers" don't need to be full references.

Comment: One trick that is sometimes used is to have a single extension pointer used for both locking and hash.  Another is to "extend" the object if it needs locking or hash (both of which are rare), placing new fields at the end of the object.

Answer (score 2):

> When one creates an object in java a certain memory-space is occupied on the heap - correct?

Probably, but the JVM can place it on the stack or optimise it away completely.

> But what is part of this memory?

If you have a generational collector, small objects are placed in the Eden space and large objects are placed in tenured space.

> Is it membervariables or both membervariables and methods?

Just variables.  The object has a link to the class which holds all the loaded methods.

> Could it be so that several object that refers to the same class share something?

Yes, of course. But this is not a requirement, just a more optimal solution.

> 1) How could this be depicted in the computers memory?

A 64-bit JVM has a 16-bytes header which include the hashCode and a reference to the class.  This is followed by the fields.  To improve memory access, the wider fields appear together to reduce the amount of padding needed.

> 2) Could the same "architecture" of how things are stored in memory concerning objects be applied to c++ as well?

For C++ object with virtual methods, they will have a link to the vtable also.

Answer (score 1):

Object data goes on the heap, Class data and member functions are shared

Answer (score 1):

The Java language spec doesn't specify heap layout. In practice, most Java objects are going to have at least a "vtable pointer" (terminology questionable) which points to a table of method vectors (possibly method pointers, but also quite possibly a series of 'jump' instructions) and other run-time type information, and then data members. So with your example, the heap layout of the object might look like:

```
(4 bytes) vtable pointer (points to MyClass vtable)
(4 bytes) age
(8 bytes) date of birth
```

For any two objects of the same class, the vtable pointer should have the same value. So, the table of method vectors, and the methods themselves, are each present only once in the address space.

Please bear in mind that is just a (simplified) example and implementations of Java need not adhere to this.

Regarding the second part of your question, C++ uses the same techniques; but again, heap layout isn't specified completely in the language spec. Of course objects in C++ need not necessarily be stored on the heap (and the same is true in Java when certain optimizations come into play), but the memory layout of an object is generally not dependent on where it is allocated.

Comment: Do not confuse people. `C++` uses fundamentally different approach. The object in `C++` is the memory itself, not a reference/handle to it.

Comment: @qwm - not sure what you mean; I'm quite specifically talking about heap layout here, which is what the question is asking about.

Comment: then you're most likely not answering the question. The question was `how things are stored in memory concerning objects`, and in C++ it has nothing to do with heap. Just wanted you to edit your answer to be more specific.

Comment: I've edited it, although I think this is a bit of a nit-pick. C++ objects can be stored on the heap, and even if they are not the layout is unlikely to be different.